# Handler scripts inside an Add-on

Tags: python

How can I put a handler script inside an Add-on? I've tried to put it into
the execute() function of an operator, but that's not working. The documentation about handlers
couldn't help me...

The goal would be, to start the handler with a button in the UI - it should not start when the Add-on is enabled.
Sadly, I couldn't find an example for this anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bare Bones Approach.**

Can simply use an update on a boolean property button to start (add) and stop (remove) a handler.

The button is added to the window manager object, and will be False when blender is loaded (or addon is first enabled)

For testing the button is added to the footer of the text editor. The frame change post handler is used as a test case.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty 

def foogle(scene):
    print("Keep on Foogling", scene.frame_current)

def toggle_handler(self, context):
    print("Toggle Handler")
    if self.toggle_handler:
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(foogle)
    else:
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(foogle)


def draw(self, context):
    wm = context.window_manager
    self.layout.prop(wm, "toggle_handler", toggle=True)
    
def register():
    bpy.types.WindowManager.toggle_handler = BoolProperty(
            update=toggle_handler,
            )
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.append(draw)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Great, this works how I want it to.Thank you batFINGER! But I'm a little confused about two things: Why can you add "self" to a function outside of a class? And why is the BoolProperty a Button in the UI? When I use a BoolProperty, it's always a Checkbox.

Comment: `toggle = True` displays it as an embossed button.  `self` is an instance of the object with an update method.  window manager in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
bl_info = {
"name" : "Test",                "author" : "Public",
"version" : (1, 0),             "blender" : (2, 90, 0),
"location" : "View3d > Tool",   "category" : "3D View",
}
import bpy, blf
font_id = 0

class Test_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.test_operator"
    bl_label = "test"
    handle = None

    @staticmethod
    def if_none(one):  pass

    def_draw = if_none

    @staticmethod
    def try_draw(self):     # Debug: When open new file
        try:    self.NONE
        except:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(Test_operator.handle, 'WINDOW')
            Test_operator.handle = None     ; print("DRAW DONE")
            Test_operator.def_draw = Test_operator.if_none

    @staticmethod
    def if_draw(self):
        blf.size(font_id, 72, 72)           ; blf.position(font_id, 50, 50, 0)
        blf.color(font_id, 1, 1, 1, 0.5)    ; blf.draw(font_id, self.text)

    @staticmethod
    def draw_callback_px(self, context):
        Test_operator.try_draw(self)            ; Test_operator.def_draw(self)

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':
            Test_operator.def_draw = Test_operator.if_none
            context.area.tag_redraw()   ; return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.text = "HELLO"     ; self.NONE = None
        Test_operator.def_draw = Test_operator.if_draw
        Test_operator.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
            Test_operator.draw_callback_px, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)  ; context.area.tag_redraw()
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

class My_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "MY_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Item"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.row().operator("object.test_operator", text = "Call operator")

classes = (Test_operator, My_Panel)
def register():
    for c in classes:   bpy.utils.register_class(c)
def unregister():
    for c in classes:   bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
if __name__ == "__main__":  register()
```

Comment: Hello, could you add a little info about what this does ?

Comment: Just a example to show some text in 3Dviewport when press the button. May be I misread the question of the questioner.

Comment: @ X Y , Yes, you misunderstood the Question. It's about a "handler" script. bpy.app.handlers. batFINGER gave me, what I was looking for.